# How do I change a field's value in preUpdate event listener?

Tags: doctrine-orm

Documentation says:

> Changes to fields of the passed entities are not recognized by the flush operation anymore, use the computed change-set passed to the event to modify primitive field values.

But it also says:

> getEntityChangeSet() to get a copy of the changeset array. Changes to this returned array do not affect updating.

Does this mean I can not change fields of an entity in preUpdate event listener? If not, how would I go about accomplishing this update?

Comment: please provide link to that documentation

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Apparently you need to recompute the changeset yourself for the changes to take effect:

```
$em = $args->getEntityManager();
$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
$uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for related entities, even though the @cascade annotation is set.

Comment: It seems that in doctrine changing the original entity will work because the the change set is [always recomputed after `preUpdate`](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blame/2.15.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1257), so I'm not sure this workaround was ever needed in fact

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can use PreUpdateEventArgs class (http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.Event.PreUpdateEventArgs.html). Forexample:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if ($entity instanceof Product)
    {
        $args->setNewValue(
            "discount",
             123
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: A problem with this method is if you want to do setNewValue on a field which was not previously changed. Since the field wasn't already in the changeset, an error is thrown. DavidW's answer gets around this limitation.

Comment: @DaveLancea A little late to the party but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70785906/1320374) explains how you can achieve the same in a different event.

Comment: The implementation is so dumb... Why, oh why, do they have to throw an exception if you want to register a new change?...

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is partially wrong when looking at the [code of doctrine](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blame/2.15.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1271), you can change the original entity and it will recompute the change-set before flushing automatically, this has been the case well before this question was asked

```php
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if ($entity instanceof Product)
    {
        $entity->setDiscount(123);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is mostly targeted at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930062/how-do-i-change-a-fields-value-in-preupdate-event-listener#comment25053997_10934721).

It's safe to change properties of the updated entity in `preUpdate`, but not of any of it's related entities.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/events.html#preupdate

> Changes to associations of the updated entity are never allowed in this event, since Doctrine cannot guarantee to correctly handle referential integrity at this point of the flush operation.

You **can** however do that in `onFlush`.

```php
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args): void
{
    foreach ($this->em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        if (!$entity instanceof Foo) {
            continue;
        }

        $bar = $foo->getBar();
        $bar->setBaz('Baz');

        // Tell the unit of work manually that the entity has changed
        $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet(
            $this->em->getClassMetadata(get_class($bar)),
            $bar
        );

    }
}
```