# Change not changed property in the Doctrine Event Listener

Tags: events, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I'm trying to set new value inside Doctrine event listener for property that wasn't changed before, I've got an error by caused by `PreUpdateEventArgs::assertValidField`. it says that I'm not able to change property that didn't changed before event has fired.

But what's the point of using doctrine lifecycle if I can't change anything I want to? What am I missing? Maybe there is another way to change value of the object instead of setNewValue method?

**UPD**

@joaoalves Ok, I'm gonna explain my problem more detail. I have Document A (not Entity since I'm working with MongoDB but it doesn't matter in this context), which has two properties: A::$foo and A::$bar. Both are Doctrine mapped filed with whatever type.

When I change one of these fileds, preUpdate event is fired. For instance, I've changed $foo property. Now to modify it I must use `$event->setNewValue` as explained [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/events.html#preupdate). Example:

```
public function preUpdate($event)
{
    $A = $event->getDocument();
    $A->setFoo('new value'); // this WILL NOT WORK because we have to use setNewValue()
    $event->setNewValue('foo', 'new value'); // WORKS as expected.
}
```

And here is my problem. Now If I want to modify A::$bar inside the preUpdate, I'll get an exception:

`Field "foo" is not a valid field of the document "A" in PreUpdateEventArgs`

This exception is thrown because `documentChangeSet` of the `PreUpdateEventArgs` contains no `bar`.

How can I modify bar property then?

Comment: Can you show us some code? and yes, in preUpdate event you can set values on your Object. The thing is, if you dont change anything on your entity then preUpdate event wont fire because you havent changed nothing.

Comment: i dont know if you already found the solution. The method setNewValue only works for a field that has changed. One workaround for change a value of a non changed field is the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930062/how-do-i-change-a-fields-value-in-preupdate-event-listener hope it helps you

Comment: @joaoalves thank you, this seems to be the answer.