# How can I use EventListener for update related Entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, event-listener

I create Event Listener for `preUpdate` of `Post` entity, that triggered fine, but when I try to update the related entity `Category`, it thrown an error:

```
Field "category" is not a valid field of the entity "BW\BlogBundle\Entity\Post" in PreUpdateEventArgs.
```

My Event Listener code is:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args) {
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();

    if ($entity instanceof Post) {
        $args->setNewValue('slug', $this->toSlug($entity->getHeading())); // work fine
        $args->setNewValue('category', NULL); // throw an error
        // other code...
```

My Post entity code is:

```
/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="posts")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BW\BlogBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\BW\BlogBundle\Entity\Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    // other code
```

How can I update this `Category` entity in this EvenetListener together with `Post` entity like in my example?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930062/how-do-i-change-a-fields-value-in-preupdate-event-listener/8930276#8930276) work, but only for `Post` changes. But I also need change some values of `Category` entity, for example:

```
$entity->getCategory()->setSlug('some-category-slug'); // changes not apply, nothing happens with Category entity.
```

Comment: Can't you simply do `$entity->setCategory(null)`?

Comment: @AlbertoFernández Yes, I can, but it do nothing. By the way, `$entity->setSlug('new-slug')` also do nothing. For it work, I need to use `setNewValue`, but  with related entities it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the method setNewValue only works for a field that has changed. Maybe your category is already NULL. That's why it's throw the error. Here's the sample code from [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Event.PreUpdateEventArgs.html#102-113).

```
 /**
  * Set the new value of this field.
  *
  * @param string $field
  * @param mixed $value
  */
 public function setNewValue($field, $value)
 {
     $this->assertValidField($field);

     $this->entityChangeSet[$field][1] = $value;
 }

 /**
  * Assert the field exists in changeset.
  *
  * @param string $field
  */
 private function assertValidField($field)
 {
     if ( ! isset($this->entityChangeSet[$field])) {
         throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
             'Field "%s" is not a valid field of the entity "%s" in PreUpdateEventArgs.',
             $field,
             get_class($this->getEntity())
         ));
     }
```

Comment: No, I check this value and it doesn't `NULL`. I guess that the method `setNewValue` is only for static fields (integer, string, etc.), not the related entities. But I need to change an related entity at this point.

Comment: I'm confused. Maybe you can try this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884440/change-not-changed-property-in-the-doctrine-event-listener) (look the up vote comment which link to another topic).

Comment: Thanks, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930062/how-do-i-change-a-fields-value-in-preupdate-event-listener/8930276#8930276) work! But work only for `Post` changes. If I try to change some values of `Category` entity, for example: `$entity->getCategory()->setSlug('some-category-slug')` - nothing happens.